# MVC - multiple data annotations on the same property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, annotations

I am trying to use the data annotations in MVC 3. Thus, I want to have multiple annotations on a single property. First, I want to check for the length of the username entered by the user, and show the corresponding error message if the name is not in the range of 3 to 13 characters.

When the first check has been made, I want to check for the second annotation with the Regex. Meaning, I will check for the regex for strings between 3 and 13, and for anything else, I will display the first error message.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a username")]
[StringLength(13, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage="Username must be between 3 and 13")]
[RegularExpression("^[a-z0-9.]{3,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Only the letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) and dots (.), are allowed")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Display(Name = "Username")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Now, when i enter a single character in the username field, the correct message is shown. When entering a second character, the error message from the reqex is displayed? Why? And can this be done in a different way?

Thanks,

Regards.

Comment: On postback or the client validator?

Comment: Actually, on both? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own validator that derives from ValidationAttribute. You can then implement any logic you like.

See the third post in this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1519132.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean you want to check attributes in a particular order? I'm not to sure whether an expected ordering is possible. You can always write a custom validation instead (using a cusomt attribute to combine the checks), that will give you full control over the exact message.

By the way, I assume you meant 'regex' instead of 'reqex' in reference to the RegularExpression? Then it would make a lot of sense for that message to appear < 3 characters because it is the minimum required by the regex. You could do away with the StringLength attribute, because it is redundant with the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is, perhaps, the best.  Simply remove the length requirement from the regular expression and it won't flag based on length.  Allow the `StringLength` annotation to do that job.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a username")]
[StringLength(13, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage="Username must be between 3 and 13")]
[RegularExpression("^[a-z0-9.]$", ErrorMessage = "Only the letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) and dots (.), are allowed")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Display(Name = "Username")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```